# Hide tooltip initialized with on="click" in ggvis plot

Tags: r, tooltip, ggvis

When using ggvis' tooltip feature with on="hover", the tooltip disappears when the cursor leaves the data point trigger:

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>% 
layer_points() %>% 
add_tooltip(function(df) df$wt, on = "hover")
```

The on="click" behavior is not as intuitive in my opinion. A click on the data element opens the respective tooltip. It can, however, only be closed again by opening *another* tooltip in the plot.

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>% 
layer_points() %>% 
add_tooltip(function(df) df$wt, on = "click")
```

I would expect the tooltip to be closed again when I click on the data point again or anywhere outside of the tooltip.

Is it possible to emulate such a behavior? I've experimented with `hide_tooltip`, but could not figure out how to get the shiny session from the interactive ggvis plot.

**Update 2015-01-15**

@wch will update the behavior in `ggvis 0.5` (https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/issues/250). I will check back when it is released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who comes here in the future, this is the answer I gave in the GitHub issue that will work: you can add one simple JavaScript line that will close the tooltip whenever the plot is clicked.

#### In a Shiny app

```
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

jscode <- 
"$(function() {
  $('#ggvis_plot').click(function(){ $('#ggvis-tooltip').hide(); });
})
"

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    tags$script(jscode),
    uiOutput("ggvis_ui"),
    ggvisOutput("ggvis_plot")
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    mtcars %>% 
      ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
      layer_points() %>%
      add_tooltip(function(df) df$wt, on = "click") %>%
      bind_shiny("ggvis_plot", "ggvis_ui")
  }
)
```

Note that the id you pass to the `ggvisOutput()` function must match the id used in the JavaScript line, in this case I used id=`ggvis_plot`.

#### In an interactive rmarkdown document

````
---
title: "ggvis Hide Tooltip on Click"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  html_document
---

<script>
$(function() {
  $('#ggvis_plot').click(function(){ $('#ggvis-tooltip').hide(); });
})
</script>

```{r echo = FALSE}
library(ggvis)
ggvis_plot <- reactive({
  mtcars %>% ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>% 
  layer_points() %>% 
  add_tooltip(function(df) df$wt, on = "click")
})

invisible(bind_shiny(ggvis_plot, 'ggvis_plot'))
ggvisOutput('ggvis_plot')
```
````

Note that again the id you pass to the `ggvisOutput()` function must match the id used in the JavaScript line, in this case I used id=`ggvis_plot`.